# Wine only works when there is internet

Tags: wine, winetricks

This is strange behavior I notice after I test running Windows application from different folder than Wine default folder (the application is Photoshop 2015 ) , what's make this even stranger is `Winecfg` wont start without internet connection too
Here is error messages from the terminal I got .

```
002c:fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 5.13 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
002c:fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
003c:err:service:process_send_command service protocol error - failed to write pipe!
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"PlugPlay" failed to start: 1053
0050:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0050:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.
0050:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0050:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0050:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
003c:err:service:process_send_command service protocol error - failed to write pipe!
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"SecDrv" failed to start: 1053
003c:err:service:process_send_command service protocol error - failed to write pipe!
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"winebus" failed to start: 1053
003c:err:service:process_send_command service protocol error - failed to write pipe!
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"MountMgr" failed to start: 1053
0024:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0024:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.
```

BTW I installed all required updated to make it work e.g `vc_redist`

Comment: Can you try running using the normal classic wine, not wine staging?

Comment: I did and even the installer not working at all now , I did the installation before with PlayOnLinux .